# How can i select language in Visual Studio auto-generated comments?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm very wondering because in Visual Studio sometimes auto generated comments are not a English.

For example, when i create the ATL project,

```
// DLL이 OLE에 의해 언로드될 수 있는지 결정하는 데 사용됩니다.
STDAPI DllCanUnloadNow(void)
{
    return _AtlModule.DllCanUnloadNow();
}
```

Yes, I'm using Visual Studio with Korean language pack.

So, Visual Studio auto-generated comments are Korean.

How can i change comments language?

Comment: Yes, i installed an English language pack. now VS is generate comment in English. thanks for looking this question.

Comment: If you know the solution, [answer yourself and accept it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/).

Comment: @ikh ah thanks i will do it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the English language pack. And now VS is generated comment in English!